# How do you call food that shreds a lot of crumbs?

Tags: food

Food that shreds many tiny particles when you bite it. For example, cookies or bread toast.

Comment: I call it "crumby".

Comment: You can take the word in your mother tongue and then look up the translation in a dictionary of your choice. That's what I do. Works like a charm.

Comment: [*Crumbly*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crumbly): "easily crumbled : FRIABLE." [*Friable*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/friable): "easily crumbled or pulverized."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### crumbly or crumby

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crumbly) carries the following entry:

> **crumbly** *adjective*
>
> **Consisting of or easily breaking into small fragments.**
>
> ‘the cheese has a sharp flavour and is crumbly and moist’

*[Crumby](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crumby)* also has your intended meaning:

> **crumby** *adjective*
>
> 1 **Resembling or covered in crumbs.**
>
> 2 *variant spelling of* crummy

whereas *[crummy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crummy)* is:

> **crummy** *(also* **crumby***)*
>
> *adjective, informal*
>
> 1 **Dirty, unpleasant, or of poor quality.**
>
> ‘a crummy little room’
>
> 1.1 **Unwell.**
>
> ‘I've been feeling pretty crummy the last few days’

So, *crumbly* is unproblematic, *crumby* works, though it does also have another meaning, but *crummy* (pronounced identically to *crumby*) should be avoided for your use case.